# How can I start a stoppable calculation task in iOS 5?

Tags: ios, background, progress-bar

I want to start a **calculation** task that will last for a couple of minutes. Since the solution is getting **closer and closer to the optimal solution with time**, I want to give the user a button to **stop** the calculation at any time and stick with the approximation.

But when I start my calculation in viewDidLoad the view with the stop button isn't even presented to the user until the calculation ends. So I need some kind of **background calculation process** – but how can I do this on iOS 5?

I also want to be able to **update a progress bar** in my view (with the stop button).

Here's my code in the UIViewController subclass:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // doing some initialization

    [self startCalculation]; // do this in background for stopping capabilities?
}

- (void)startCalculation {
    // start calculation and update progress bar every 200 ms or so
}
```

Could somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General answer is to call `startCalculation` from within an `NSThread`

```
//thread is a property in your corrent class
NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startCalculation) object:nil];
```

Then to stop it

```
//when you want to stop the thread
[thread cancel];
```

If you want to update a progress view from within this thread make sure to call the progress updates from the ui main thread like so

```
//in your calculation function, when you want to update the progressview
- (void)startGenerationProcess {
    //Calculations

    //update progress
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          //Update progress
    });

    //More Calculations
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do that. Sounds quite easy ... :)

Comment: you may have some difficulties along the way, but yes its quite easy :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for the [NSThread](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsthread_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class or [NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html).